# EnableSwagger confusion

Tags: c#, lambda, owin, swagger

I'm getting stuck trying to understand the Swagger & Owin template from visual studio.

I'm basically stuck right at the start:

```
var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
// Configure Swagger UI
httpConfiguration
    .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Test API"))
        .EnableSwaggerUi();
```

Where I'm confused is the lambda function the SingleApiVersion appears to come from nowhere.

How does this fit together?

I can see that the EnableSwagger extension method has two overloads:

```
(Action<SwaggerDocsConfig> configure = null) //(this is also confusing) and
(string routeTemplate, Action<SwaggerDocsConfig> configure = null)
```

So I can see that the SingleApiVersion has come from the SwaggerDocsConfig **BUT HOW!**

Thanks, sorry for the basic question, I think I've given myself a headache trying to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `SwaggerDocsConfig` as the delegate passed into `Action<T>` as `Action<SwaggerDocsConfig>`, the child member `SingleApiVersion` can be set because it returns no value.  The instance of `SwaggerDocsConfig` is instantiated in the constructor of the `EnableSwagger` method on the `HttpConfigurationExtensions` class.